# How can I pass "User Id" which has logged in to another window after closing Login Window in WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, authentication

I am creating simple To-Do List **WPF application** with User Registration and Login, and each User will be able to Add and Delete To-Do Lists and Items inside it, and every thing is saved by Entity Framework in MSSQL Database.

---

So my problem is how can I redirect the [User Id] of the User that has just logged in, to another window "Main Window" after closing the first one "Login Window" ?

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server here? Also, this is pretty broad as well; what have you tried to do to solve the problem, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I used MS-SQL to create my database which contains the users and lists tables. 
Actually, I don't find the way to get that selected (User_Id) to list his lists and items..

Comment: the SQL element is not related to passing values between windows in WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One way is to return results from from window and pass on to the other from the App.xaml.cs.

In your App.xaml, change the startupuri (Directs to a window) to startup (directs to a method).

It should look something like this.

```
<Application x:Class="TSMV.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TSMV"
         **Startup="ApplicationStart"**
        >
</Application>
```

The ApplicationStart should implement logic to display one window and then fetch the result from it. You can implement different ways to fetch the data , like, DialogResult, storing in a SingletonObject, calling a method to the window, etc. The main idea is this data is then passed on to the new window.

See the application start what i use in my project which can give you some idea.

```
private void ApplicationStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        iwndwMain = new MainWindow();
        WindowInitiations();
    }

public bool ShouldMoveOn {get;set;}

    private void WindowInitiations()
    {
        LoginProcess();
        MainWindowProcess();
    }

    private void LoginProcess()
    {
        var vmLogOn = new VMLogon(); //LogOn ViewModel
        try
        {
            LoginResult = SingletonData.Instance.GlobalDialogSerivce.ShowDialog(vmLogOn);
            ShouldMoveOn = vmLogOn.MoveOn;
            //SingletonData.Instance.GlobalUserSessionData = vmLogOn.UserSessionData; //Only when this data is filled, we can initiate the VMTimeSheet
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            string message = @"Unable to start the application. If this is a server issue, please try after sometime or try contacting the admin";
            VMConfirmationWindow vmconf = new VMConfirmationWindow(message);
            SingletonData.Instance.GlobalDialogSerivce.ShowDialog(vmconf);
        }
    }

    private void MainWindowProcess()
    {
        if (ShouldMoveOn) //Log In is Success
        {
            iwndwMain.ShowDialog();
            if (VMMain.Instance.ViewModelLogOn.IsLoggedOut == true)
            {

                WindowInitiations(); //if the user logs out, then repeat the process and show the login window
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Viewmodel first approach and implemented IOC containers to display windows and dialogs. (*Note: I'm using Haley.Flipper.MVVM nuget package for MVVM wiring.*). You can use different MVVM libraries if you wish to use IOC method or implement your own.

So, what i have done above is that, I have created a boolean property "MoveOn" inside my viewmodel for Login Window. Once the login process is successful, i set this property as true.(by default this is false)

Once the login process is done, i check the boolean property and then based on this i initiate the main window to display.

Comment: Thank you very much **Lingam**

Answer (score 0):

Muhammed. On the fly i have to fast ideas for your approach. First of all you could build an event, which will be fired, when your login window will be closed. This event would have the user id as an event argument. If your main window would subscribe to this event, it would recognise the value. Second approach would be a complete process. Its i little bit more deep, but actually not very complicated. Its completely normal, that values ares passed between different classes and views. Do open a new class, you always habe to call the constructor of this class. While calling the constructor, you can pass values to them.I have to links your my two ideas for you. Hope one of them will help you.

Way with constructor: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-constructors/

Way with event: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_events.htm

Cheers, Paul.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I will try it and give feedback.